# Send Image in Json : 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, android, json, web-services, base64

From my android I am trying to send an image with a class of data, to an IIS webservice. (C#)

The problem is I get `400 Bad request`.

The image is being encoded to `Base64`. And then placed into `json` with the rest of the class elements.

My guess is that Base64 is not valid inside a Json. So the server does not understand it.
If I set the string to be `""`, the post is accepted fine.

So the question is, **how do I make my `Base64` valid from within a `Json` array?** ( I tried URL.Encode with no success).

Or **How should you send an image from android to webservice?**

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 String json = gson.toJson(record);  // record has param { String base64Photo }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is the image? I'm pretty sure you are surpassing the IIS Json size limit (default is almost 4 MB).

Check this http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/08/05/how-to-configure-maxjsonlength-in-asp.net-ajax-applications.aspx or this http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits

Good luck!

Comment: Its something to consider, however I just took a photo, and its only 81.5KB . Since its in a Jpg format, not Bitmap. Addded the suggested code anyway, still same issue.

Comment: With some extra size limitation changes, including string and buffer size, it did infact fix my issue. Something I had already done in previous projects. So thanks! `<binding name="rest" maxBufferSize="1024000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8000192" maxArrayLength="104857600"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>`

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest - I've never uploaded an image from Android to an IIS webservice but in every other context I've always just used a `File`. It's easy to create a file and upload it as a `MultipartEntity`. Plus you avoid having to use `Base64` all together, which is good because it saves you the roughly 33% increased overhead that comes with using `Base64`.

```
private File createFileFromBm(Bitmap pic){
    File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "image");

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pic.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    return f;
}
```

Here's how you create a `MultipartEntity`

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE;              
entity.addPart("photo", new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg"));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
return httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```

I used an `HttpPost` here and a `BasicResponseHandler` to receive the `JSON` output from the server for processing but you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Ok, if I had a FileBody as part of my class, how would the server represent this? Just use of `File` type parameter?

Comment: If you can yes. When I do this using PHP there's just an incoming File array that takes this kind of input. I'd guess theres on in IIS but I don't really know.